# Compare a remote file with a local file in java

Tags: java, file-upload, selenium-webdriver, remote-server

I'm testing a web app with selenium and I run the test on a remote XP VM. In my test, I douwnload a file and I want to compare this file with a local one. Can I compare these two files : 
This is a part of the code :

```
 //the local file path
    File file1 = new File("C:/export_transaction.csv");
 //the remote file path
    File file2 = new File("C:/Documents and Settings/Export_Transaction.csv");


    Properties prop1 = new Properties();
    Properties prop2 = new Properties();
    prop1.load(new FileReader(file1));
    prop2.load(new FileReader(file2));

   Assert.assertEquals(prop1, prop2);
```

The problem is that I can't access to the remote file path. Is there a way to specify the path of the remote file ?
Please help !

Comment: Do you just want to check whether the files are equal or a line by line comparision with change block detection as VCS would do?

Comment: A .csv file doesn't have the format for being loaded as a Property object. -- And: If you can't access the remote file you won't be able to read it.

Comment: No, I just want to check if the two files are equal. No need to check line by line. My only problem is I can't access to the remote file by doing : File file = new File("C:/Documents and Settings/Export_Transaction.csv");

Comment: This is not a Selenium problem! You will to access the remote machine's file system. You will need to execute a system command on the remote machine; see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331178/how-to-use-selenium-grid-to-run-some-commands-on-the-node-and-system-commands-lo for some ideas. You will then have to find the `md5` of the remote file and of the local file, and compare those.

Comment: Thank you for your proposition, but I think you didn't really understand my problem. I need to access a file which is not on my computer. The IP adresse of the computer where the file is located is for example : 10.0.0.1 How can I access to that file on that computer from another computer. I tried this, but no result ! File file = new File("//10.0.0.1/C:/Téléchargements/Transaction_20140703.csv");